# how to assign objects from the constructor using references in C#

Tags: c#, reference, ref, out

There are three classes.

The controller class is running a module that assigns an object to a variable called _goCharacter.

The Center class is central, which is intended to handle the Interaction class.

The _goCharacter object that we're trying to address in the interaction class is an object in the controller.

The problem is that the _goCharacter object is initially null and will continue to change in the future.

So I'm always assigning them to the center class, but it doesn't seem to be good for performance.

I found out that if I use ref and out to assign a reference, I can use it as a reference without having to reallocate it every time.

Please advise me what to do.

```
class Controller{
    public GameObject _goCharacter = null;


   void func(){   // Objects are assigned while other modules are running.
        _goCharacter = .....
        // Assign an object to the _goCharacter.
    }

}


class Center{

    private GameObject _goCharacter;
    private Interaction interaction;

    void Start(){
        interaction = new Interaction();
    }
    void Update(){

        _goCharacter = Controller.GetComponent<Controller>()._goCharacter; 
        interaction.setObject(_goCharacter);      // Reallocate each time.
        interaction.func2();
    }

}


class Interaction{
    private GameObject _goCharacter; 

    public Interaction(){

    }

    public Interaction(GameObject _goCharacter){
        this._goCharacter = _goCharacter;    
    }

    public void setObject(){
        this._goCharacter = _goCharacter;    
    }

    public func2(){
        // Function dealing with _goCharacter
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can try to use DI Container.

Comment: This link can useful for you: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1237556/Exploring-Dependency-Injection-in-Csharp-part